# show English keyboard and type when device language is Arabic in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard

I am doing a app having two languages,
What I am doing is,
On first page I have several fields that will take input from user.
which contain one filed as Email id of the user.

When I change my device language to Arabic, All textfield I type values like first name and last name etc are in Arabic,
But for email id I need the keyboard and type in English.

I tried a lot for the same that to change keyboard type for this particular filed, but failed.

any inputs and guidance is welcome.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a local variable

```
BOOL isEmailField;
```

Implement the Email Text fields "Editing did begin:" and "Editing did end:" like the following way:

```
- (IBAction)emailTextFieldBeginEdit:(id)sender {

    isEmailField = YES;
}

- (IBAction)emailTextFieldEndEdit:(id)sender {
    isEmailField = NO;
}
```

Now implement the method:

```
 - (UITextInputMode *) textInputMode
```

Use like this:

```
- (UITextInputMode *) textInputMode {

    if(isEmailField) {
        for (UITextInputMode *inputMode in [UITextInputMode activeInputModes]) {

            if([inputMode.primaryLanguage isEqualToString:@"en-US"]) {
                return inputMode;
            }
        }
    }
    return [super textInputMode];
}
```

Hope this will work, and please let me know your feedback.

Comment: Waw.....
its working, thanks. Also this helps me to solve the problem for Numeric keyboard

Comment: Can I apply the same logic, for datepickerview and timepickerview. I tried but failed, any guidance